# Postgres CASE with multiple data types

Tags: postgresql

I have a table with the following columns:Sample dataset

| employee_id | value_storage_type | value_date | value_decimal | value_string |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 22864 | string | NULL | NULL | 3D |
| 22897 | decimal | NULL | 1.000000 | NULL |

I have build a query that renders this data grouped by employee using

```
SELECT json_object_agg(regexp_replace(custom_fields_1.name::text, '[^a-zA-Z0-9]'::text, '_'::text, 'g'::text),
                CASE custom_fields.data_type
                    WHEN 'date'::text THEN fv.value_date::text::character varying
                    WHEN 'number'::text THEN fv.value_decimal::text::character varying
                    ELSE fv.value_string
                END)::jsonb AS db_json_data
           FROM abc.custom_fields
GROUP BY abc.employee_id
```

This query works, however any decimal data is being cast as a String

```
{
    "Married": null,
    "TShirt_Size": "M",
    "Dependant_DOB": null,
    "Dependant_Sex": null,
    "Salary": "300.00000",
    "Dependant_Name_": "Joe Smith",
    "Beneficiary_Name": null,
    "Beneficiary_Percentage": null,
    "Single_Family_Coverage": "Active"
}
```

I'm looking for data like

```
{
    "Married": null,
    "TShirt_Size": "M",
    "Dependant_DOB": null,
    "Dependant_Sex": null,
    "Family_Members": 300.00000,
    "Dependant_Name_": "Joe Smith",
    "Beneficiary_Name": null,
    "Beneficiary_Percentage": null,
    "Single_Family_Coverage": "Active"

}
```

I want to preserve the data types but CASE doesn't allow for different data types comparison or casting in one statement. How can I achieve this ?

Comment: Could you edit your question and share the simple data as text not image ?

Comment: As explained in the [question guide](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask), please do not post [pictures](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/285551) of data.

Comment: Updated the question, sorry for not catching this

Answer (score 0):

Cast the `*_value` columns to jsonb early to avoid the `case` construct:

```
select employee_id, 
       jsonb_object_agg(
         name, 
         coalesce(
           to_jsonb(value_date), 
           to_jsonb(value_decimal), 
           to_jsonb(value_string)
         )
       )
  from custom_fields
 group by employee_id;
```

[Working fiddle.](https://dbfiddle.uk/Titb4dtb)